# Does this linear system have no solutions?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations

Am I correct in saying if I have a linear system where a variable equals two different outputs, then there are no solutions? E.g., 
$$\begin{cases}x= 4 \\ x=5\end{cases}$$

Comment: Can you clarify?

Comment: imagine you had the first variable plus two times the second variable equals one in the first row , in the second row you have 3 times  the third variable equals -4 and in the third row the third variable equals equals 1

Comment: So the three equations $x+2y = 1$ and $3z = -4$ and $z = 1$? There is definitely no solution to this system of equations; simply because the latter two equations contradict each other.

Comment: Also, matrices don't have or not-have solutions. Equations, and systems of equations, have or don't-have solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Yes,
because there is 
no value of $x$
that satisfies both
$x=4$
and
$x=5$.

Answer (score 1):

> In your case case, it is just like having a game where the second rule says
>   not to follow the first rule: it is impossible to play a game like
>   that.
>
> That system doesn’t have a solution because we are asking x to be 1 and 2 at
>   the same time. This is just like asking your neighbor to be male and
>   female at the same time!

[Source: Overdetermined and underdetermined systems of equations put simply](http://quickmathintuitions.org/intuition-for-overdetermined-and-underdetermined-systems-of-equations/)

Answer (score 0):

**For another point of view**

Geometrically, the graph of $x = 4$ is a vertical line which intersects the $x$-axis at the point $(4, 0)$.  Similarly, the graph of $x = 5$ is (*another*) vertical line which intersects the $x$-axis at the point $(5, 0)$.  Clearly, as your system of equations is represented by two parallel lines which are not coincident, then the system is *inconsistent*.  We conclude that the system of equations does not have a solution.

Here is the WolframAlpha plot for these two lines:

[image: WolframAlpha plot for $x = 4$ and $x = 5$]